# trigger.io with xcode 6.4 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: trigger.io

While running trigger.io project from trigger tool kit I am getting an error as following . I have tried every possible suggesting on the internet still unable to locate the answer . In my trigger account i and defined 'Device" not simulator

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke239 in parse.a(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke332 in parse.a(PFObject.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld build/ForgeInspector.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.build/Objects-normal/i386/Forge normal i386
    cd /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/opt/xcode/6.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/xcode/6.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/stable/stable-python-env/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /opt/xcode/6.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /opt/xcode/6.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -L/var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/build/Release-iphonesimulator -F/var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app -filelist /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/build/ForgeInspector.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.build/Objects-normal/i386/ForgeInspector.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/ForgeCore/build/Release-iphonesimulator/Forge -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AssetsLibrary -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/geolocation.a -weak_framework CoreLocation -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/tabs.a -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/media.a -weak_framework MediaPlayer -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/notification.a -weak_framework QuartzCore -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/request.a -weak_framework Security -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/parse.a -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework CFNetwork -weak_framework CoreGraphics -weak-lsqlite3 -weak-lz.1.1.3 -weak_framework MobileCoreServices -weak_framework Social -weak_framework StoreKit -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/prefs.a -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/facebook.a -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/display.a -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/file.a -weak_library /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/urlhandler.a -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/build/ForgeInspector.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.build/Objects-normal/i386/ForgeInspector_dependency_info.dat -o /var/folders/mb/76wdt_854yx70r_wg6_w45g40000b0/T/tmpnKUfEO/ios/app/build/ForgeInspector.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.build/Objects-normal/i386/Forge
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_BFTaskMultipleExceptionsException", referenced from:
      ___53+[PFObject(Private) deleteAllAsync:withSessionToken:]_block_invoke239 in parse.a(PFObject.o)
      ___65+[PFObject(Private) _deepSaveAsync:withCurrentUser:sessionToken:]_block_invoke332 in parse.a(PFObject.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/ForgeInspector.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Forge normal x86_64
    Ld build/ForgeInspector.build/Release-iphonesimulator/ForgeInspector.build/Objects-normal/i386/Forge normal i386
(2 failures)

[   INFO] 2015-08-21 14:08:25,733 -- cleaning up source directories
[  ERROR] 2015-08-21 14:08:25,734 -- Xcode error
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the Parse module you are using and make sure the latest Facebook module is included. The Facebook module is required if you're using Parse.